# show escape sequences in terminal?

Tags: terminal

Is there a way to let the terminal show the raw escape sequence? (e.g. those used to control color)

I came across this UNIX.SE question, and want to filter "red" output ( [Filter output of command by color](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134763))

However, the commands in the answers do not work for my output (e.g. the red in `git status` for "Untracked files"). They do work for the examples there `echo -e '\033[00;31mtest\033[00m' | grep --color=none '[[:cntrl:]]'`. Filtering with `grep --color=none '[[:cntrl:]]'` works on my output but also shows text with other colors.

I guess the red I see must be a different red than `\e[31m`.

*Is there a way to let terminal output raw escape sequences?* (so that I can use the right sequence to filter the specific red color I see)

(bash, Ubuntu 18.04)

-- Update --

For clarification, my question is on how to show the raw escape sequence.

@egmont' answer using `script` worked. Basically, I just needed to use `script` to record the output and use one of the answers to the above [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134763) to find the red color text, e.g.:

```
script /tmp/a.txt
git status
exit
cat /tmp/a.txt | grep -Eo $'\e\\[31m[^\e]*\e\\[[03]?m'
```

The other answer/comments are also correct in pointing out that my usage of `git` didn't get the color through the pipe.

Comment: `git status` only produces color when its output is to a terminal, not in a pipeline. This is the case for most commands actually. So if you're trying to filter one of these commands by color, you'll first have to convince it to send the color into the pipeline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

I think you want to *examine* what a certain utility (like `git status`) sends to the terminal emulator. Am I right?

Start up the `script` utility, it makes a log of exactly this. Then call `git status` or whatever you want. Then exit from `script`'s shell, it'll notify you that a file called `typescript` has been created. Open this file in a text editor to find the sequences you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

> I guess the red I see must be a different red than `\e[31m`.

You guess wrongly.

```
% ptybandage git status . | grep rules | console-decode-ecma48
TAB
SGR 31
'm'
'o'
'd'
'i'
'f'
'i'
'e'
'd'
':'
' '
' '
' '
'r'
'u'
'l'
'e'
's'
SGR 0
CR
LF
% git status . | grep rules | console-decode-ecma48
TAB
'm'
'o'
'd'
'i'
'f'
'i'
'e'
'd'
':'
' '
' '
' '
'r'
'u'
'l'
'e'
's'
LF
%
```

You haven't made `git` think that it is writing to a terminal, so it isn't producing colour.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283984/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  "[`console-decode-ecma48`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/console-decode-ecma48.xml)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.